# CNTK: Access to trained model data

Tags: python, cntk

I have trained a model in CNTK using Python API.   I would like to implement the network in code on an Android device.

Is there a way that I can access the network weights and then code the network directly without using the CNTK libraries?

Can I get access to the model in human readable form?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you sure can. The information can be found on CNTK github ("how do I" section).

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Load-model-and-access-network-weights-(parameters)

Comment: Do you have any guidance on how to best go about re-implementing the network?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the model trained by CNTK to txt format with CNTK's dumpnode command. Here is contents config file txt.conf:

```
command = convert2txt

convert2txt = [
    action = "dumpnode"    
    modelPath="./cntkSpeechFF.dnn.5"
    nodeName = "Prior" # if not specified, all nodes will be printed
    outputFile = "./cntkSpeechFF.dnn.5.txt" # the path to the output file. If not specified a file name will be automatically generated based on the modelPath.

    printValues = true
    printMetadata = true

]
```

Then you run cntk as

```
cntk configFile=txt.conf
```